# 500 server error when denying access to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to deny direct access to a subdirectory using .htaccess:

```
# Deny direct access
<Directory "/cron">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

The above code is in the .htaccess file of my public_html directory. The subdirectory I am trying to block is located at public_html/cron.

When I enter an address within the /cron folder directly in the browser, I get a 500 server error instead of a 403. Any idea why?

Comment: No, but your apache error log can tell you what's wrong whenever you get 500

Comment: @michael I just checked the error log and it says `<Directory not allowed here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `<Directory>` in `.htaccess` files.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#directory

> Context:  server config, virtual host

Use in your `/cron/.htaccess`file:

```
deny from all
```